# C code compiles in Windows, gives compilation error on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Contents of somefile.h:

```
#ifndef __SOMEFILE_H
#define __SOMEFILE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct _table_t
{
     void (*somefunction1)();
     void (*somefunction2)(int a);
     void (*somefunction3)(int a, int *b);
}table_t;

void doSomething1();
void doSomething2();

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // error at this line: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
#endif
#endif
```

Shown above is the code snippet and the error I get when I compile my code on Linux. The same code compiles fine on Windows with no complaints.

About the source file:

```
all.h is a header file which includes:
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
#include "somefile.h"
```

Here is the content of somefile.c

```
#include "all.h" 
#include "header4.h"
jumptable_t jumptable_a = 
{
       a_function1();
       a_function2(int a);
       a_function3(int a, int *b);
}

//more code
void function1()
{
     a_function1();
}

void function2(int a)
{
    a_function2(a);
}

void function3(int a, int *b)
{
    a_function3(a, b);
}


void doSomething1()
{

}
void doSomething2()
{

}
```

Comment: Assuming this header is being included into a C++ source file, are there any other headers included above it?

Comment: Yes, this header file is included in C++ source file.

Comment: No, there are no other header files included above it.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal C++ source file that triggers the bug?  Also, I imagine this header has been sanitised (I hope you don't actually call your file `somefile.h`) -- have you verified that this version still fails?

Comment: yes, my file name is somefile.h. Is this a problem?

Comment: Compiles fine for me with g++ 4.4.6.  Please post the source file where this is included.

Comment: This file is actually included in another .h file, say all.h and this file, all.h is included in most .c and .cpp files.

Comment: @RRR Post the code please; there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted so far.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I have posted the source file, this is how it roughly looks. please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: @RRR OK cheers, and which header file is `somefile.h`?

Comment: now, all.h includes somefile.h

Comment: The initializer for `jumptable_t` is invalid. Possibly that is actually the source of the error

Comment: if you are sharing code between C and C++, avoid parameter list `()` as it has different meaning in each language. Use `(void)` to indicate no parameters.

Comment: `header4.h` may have an error (the one that is included directly after the one that appears to give the error)

Answer (score 2):

Macro with leading double underscores is illegal. You need to change your include guard.

Comment: Please let me know what do you mean by - You need to change your include guard. Thanks.

Comment: @RRR, `#ifndef __SOMEFILE_H
#define __SOMEFILE_H` That's include guard.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `;` after the `}` of `jumptable_a`. And use commas instead of semicolons in the initializer of `jumptable_a`.

The braces make it look like a somethink function-like, but it's not.

Also, in `somefile.h` the struct is called `table_t`, but in `somefile.c` you are using `jumptable_t`, which I assume is an error introduced when writing the post here.

Comment: The initializer would still be invalid even after those changes, it's really nothing resembling valid code. Possibly he meant `{&function1, &function2, &function3}` as the initializer (with those functions being declared first of course)

Comment: Oh right. I first just saw the missing semicolon, then the missing commas and missed the remaining things.
Good job, me.